# What happens if I use fresh mushrooms to make vegetarian Chinese mushroom soup (冬菇湯)?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

What changes if I use fresh mushrooms, rather than dried, to make Chinese mushroom soup (冬菇湯)? I'll be shunning meat. Note that unlike Western mushroom soups, mushrooms aren't blended in Chinese soups.

[Top](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-three-virtues-vegetarian-restaurant-p1698715). [Middle](https://www.dimcook.com/recipe/a6bb65d965/%E7%B4%A0%E6%B9%AF-%E5%86%AC%E8%8F%87%E6%A0%97%E5%AD%90%E6%B9%AF). [Bottom](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g294217-d816180-i305229010-Celestial_Court_Chinese_Restaurant-Hong_Kong.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Side note: not all “Western mushroom soups” are blended. You may be thinking of the (canned) cream of mushroom soup, but that’s just one of many ways to serve mushrooms in soup form.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks. Actually I wasn't thinking of mushroom soups with cream. "Western" restaurants' mushroom soups usually are blended? I don't see a original whole mushroom like in the pictures above.

Answer (score 2):

Fresh/raw mushrooms are quite bland by themselves (yes I know there are exceptions).

I suggest pan fry in oil them before using them in the soup, or chop them up and bake them in the oven on a sheet pan.

When you are using dried mushroom, you will re-hydrate them in water and you will usually use the resulting liquid which contains a lot of flavor in the recipe.

Comment: Agreed -- dried mushrooms have a much deeper flavor than their fresh versions.  They also have a chewier texture, which roasting in the oven might help with.